# Change selected "answer"?

Tags: discussion

I received my answer from person A, and I accepted it! A few days later, person B adds another answer to my question, and his/her answer is more comprehensive and useful for me and for future visitors.

Is it unethical to select the new answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: Choose the better answer, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: If you were locked in for doing that, the system wouldn't let you. Go right ahead.

Comment: @DanielA.White Good point, but this capability is necessary for case of unintentional selecting a wrong answer(for example accidental click) ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you should, and you are encourage to change your accepted answer. This way, when users arrive at your question via search, the best answer will be displayed first.

I've experienced cases where I search up a question, do exactly what the accepted answer tells me to do, it doesn't quite work, then I scroll down and find a much easier solution.

Also, I've seen some questions where the accepted answer "somewhat" solves the problem, and then the second answer (with 100+ votes) answers it again using a much more elegant way. Sometimes, you can even see people commenting below the second answer, telling the asker to "accept this one instead."

Comment: +1, There are no feelings on stackoverflow